# Cannot view folders on client with VPN to 2008 server

Tags: networking, vpn, discovery

Recently installed server 2008 as part of our upgrade from 2003 and managed to resolve most problems but left with the last one which is that I cannot view folders or files on 2008 server from client with VPN access.

When VPN is established I can achieve the following:-

Ping fine from client to servers broadband facing Nic and also internal LAN Nic. Can also access our CCTV system cameras that exist on the local network without any problem.

Looking at other posts one possible problem seemed to be Network Discovery so started the following and left on Automatic:-

```
    DNS Client
    Function Discovery Resource Publication
    SSDP Discovery
    UPnP Device Host
```

Then configured the Windows firewall to allow Network Discovery.

Had a look at the security database - Clients - Network Discovery and it stated that all the above elements were installed but Network Discovery policy was disabled.

So went into Advanced Firewall, Group Policy, edited the Domain GPO, created Inbound rule and set Network Discovery to allow on all with similar rule creation in Outbound. Checked that this rule had filtered down to all other groups, which it had.

Went back to look at security database - Clients etc and it still stated that policy was disabled.

I have run out of ideas and cannot see anywhere else that the Network Discovery can be enabled. I suppose more to the point, is this the problem in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occurs in scenarios where the dependency services for Network Discovery are not running (or)The Windows firewall or other firewalls do not allow Network Discovery.

To fix the above issue follow the steps given below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2722035

IF that was not working for you. try enabling 'Device Association service' and also check whether  IP version 6 was enabled

Comment: Yes already followed the microsoft advise because identified Network Discovery was not running. Could you confirm where I would find 'device association service'? IPV6 is disabled on both NIC interfaces and just running on IPV4. Thanks, John